# Cast to type stored in variable

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, deserialization

I have something like this:

```
foreach (XAttribute attr in element.Attributes())
{
    object value = GetValue(attr.Name.ToString());
    Type type = null;
    if (value != null)
    {
        type = value.GetType();
    }

    SetValue(attr.Name.ToString(), (type)attr.Value);
}
```

What am i trying over here? Some deserialization is under way - i have some XML serialized data which looks like this:

```
<Item Id="5" Name="Test" Visible="False">....
```

Everything is stored in strings. Now, based on *Name* property i know what object I am deserializing and in base class (let's call it *ItemTemplate*) I have this *Parse* function. In this function, I iterate over XML attributes and tying to set values (since I don't have public setters and I can't have them there is no way to use some kind of XmlDeserialization) using following function:

```
public void SetValue(string propertyName, object value)
{
    var property = this.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
    if (property != null)
    {
        property.SetValue(this, value, null);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Property name '" + propertyName + "' not found!");
    }
}
```

You can see the problem over here. I need to cast *attr.Value* to proper type before calling *SetValue*. Based on *attr.Name*, I know which property type I need and here comes the problem - how I cast this *attr.Value* to something of right type (other than string, for example Int, Boolean...)? Of course that function in first code snippet won't work because you can't use variable as type.

tl; dr - My goal is to cast values of some XML attributes to proper types based on some reflection and attribute names. How can I do it?

Comment: You're over-complicating your work. Because then in your program you'll never be certain what value contains what type. Determine ahead of time what value (and its type) you'll be storing in each element / attribute and work from there. In your example, instead of your program figuring out the type, you should plan for all Name's to be strings, Visible's to be bool etc. Otherwise is Id an int, long, uint etc? You can't "determine" it from its current value.

Comment: Some places it's necessary to hard-code values, such as in data storage. You should in a data-storage know the type of each value stored and keep it consistent. Imagine another person than yourself figuring out this scheme you're creating 10 years down the road. Think they'll have a clue what you're doing?

Comment: I think I am onto something - using this "type" variable as switch for determining how to convert each of attributes. @ChuckSavage - I am trying to avoid need for anyone in future to even think what is going on - _GenerateXML_ will always output same data (`<Item Property=Value.../>`) and _ParseXML_ should always depend on this Item class as template for deserialization, exactly like _GenerateXML_ depends on that same template for generating XML in first place.

Comment: Show us more xml and more classes.

Comment: You don't have public setters - Ok. Can you create objects with public constructors?

Comment: Seconding the first comment. The main purpose of types is for ensuring type safety when you're writing and compiling your code. It's better if you back up a step and describe what the larger problem is that you're trying to solve. 90% of the time (or more) if you're trying to figure out what the type of something is at runtime then the design is flawed.